# Insert image path into database not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to insert image path into database table so I can later display it on a different place but only thing that is getting inserted into the table is the folder name where pictures are uploaded into and the image name is missing.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require "connect.php";

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

$uploaddir = 'uploaded';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $filepath = $uploaddir . $filename;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp,$filepath);
    $filepath=addslashes($filepath);
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE vijesti SET imeslike='$filepath' WHERE id='$id'");
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
<div id="main">
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Table column named `imeslike` is supposed to be updated with image path but it only shows `uploaded/`. It's like it does not accept variables when I put some random string in my query it gets updated and the string value shows up in the `imeslike` column.

The uploaded folder is in same directory so the relative path is OK and I also tried absolute path like:

```
$uploaddir="C:/wamp/www/admirovsajt/uploaded"
```

But same problem.

Comment: please provide information about `imeslike` column

Comment: Your code is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection, just using MySQLi does not make your code secure, kindly read on prepared statements or properly sanitize the data before using it on a SQL query. Aside from that, does `echo $filename;` properly show the image name? Was the upload successful did you check that before continuing? Does it show no error? You should save the relative URL path if you want to display it on your website, saving the local path will become a problem at a later stage.

Comment: imeslike is varchar(255)

Comment: where do you check whether imeslike column is updated? direclty from the db or on some other page? Could you also specify what value imeslike column gets when you used an absolute path?

Comment: ok image is not being uploaded the direectory is empty and i tried echoing out $filename and it is not getting echoed.I check directly in the database to see if the column is updated and when i use absolute path the same shows in the column(uploaded/)

Comment: @admir I will suggest you that you read http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and move from there. Also since you're on windows use [copy](http://br1.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) or [rename](http://br1.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) instead of `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Are your files uploading ok? Because your missing your submit button name and the your validating against that name.

Comment: Not to mention there is no ID on the form or on the action link.

Comment: when i remove if(isset($_POST['submit'])) i can echo out $filename but image is not being uploaded

Comment: `echo $_GET['id'];` and as for image is not being uploaded check my previous comment with links to how to check that.

Comment: ok i added submit name and nothing happended it is like databes is not getting updated but the files are being uploaded i can see them in uploaded dir

Comment: id is from another page where i display the title from the news table and i have put a link for adding pictures like echo $title."<a href='index.php?id=$id'>Add picture</a>";

Comment: Yes but you do not retain that on your form action so its lost when u submit it.

Comment: Do you mean? <form action="index.php" method="post" id="<?php echo $id;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>

Comment: `<form action="index.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"` or you can add it as a hidden field like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">` and change it on your code from `GET` to `POST`.

Comment: ok it works now..thank you very much i've been struggling for three days trying to get this to work and you really saved me

Comment: Your code still very poor, you should properly handle upload errors so you know if and when something happens, your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL Injection and you're not making sure the file has been moved from temp directory to the actual directory and is right as in size etc.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that image was uploaded before looking for correct path in the database.

instead of:

```
$uploaddir = 'uploaded';
```

try

```
$uploaddir = 'uploaded/';
```

Comment: i did that and nothing happens

Comment: are your images being inserted into the uploaded directory?

Comment: try using mysql_real_escape_string($filename) instead of addslashes($filename)

Comment: "UPDATE vijesti SET imeslike='$filepath' WHERE id='$id'" -----
You can test it as:
$SQL = "UPDATE vijesti SET imeslike='$filepath' WHERE id=".$id;
mysqli_query($conn, $SQL);

Comment: Remove the addslashes function from $filepath. Another variant for SQL can be --- "UPDATE vijesti SET imeslike='".$filepath."' WHERE id=".$id;
-- Provided that you can get the $filepath, it should go in the db without problem.

Comment: before SQL, echo $filepath. And see the output. If output is not there, $filepath variable is empty and there is nothing going in the db. If $filepath is showing the path, there is an error in the query, which should be resolved through above statement. Because mySQL is not showing error, best bet is that there is nothing in $filepath variable. Also confirm the output for $id variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
require "connect.php";

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  echo $id = $_GET['id'];
}

$uploaddir = 'uploaded/';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $pid = $_POST['pid'];
  $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $filepath = $uploaddir . $filename;
  move_uploaded_file($tmp,$filepath);
  $filepath=addslashes($filepath);
  mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE vijesti SET imeslike='$filepath' WHERE id='$pid'");
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
<div id="main">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="pid" value="<?php echo $id;?>">  
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="upload"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added one line in the existing code to post the value when we update data into the database.
<input type="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">

Comment: if you find the answer useful, please upvote it. thanks.